# Boost Python - Limits to the number of arguments when wrapping a function

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I'm using Boost Python to wrap some C++ functions that I've created.  One of my C++ functions contains 22 arguments.  Boost complains when I try to compile my solution with this function, and I'm trying to figure out if it is just because this function has too many arguments.

Does anyone know if such a limit exists?  I've copied the error I'm getting below, not the code because I figure someone either knows the answer to this or not - and if there is no limit then I'll just try to figure it out myself.  Thanks very much in advance!

Here is a copy of the beginning of the error message I receive...

```
1>main.cpp

1>c:\cpp_ext\boost\boost_1_47\boost\python\make_function.hpp(76): error C2780: 'boost::mpl::vector17<RT,most_derived<Target,ClassT>::type&,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14> boost::python::detail::get_signature(RT (__thiscall ClassT::* )(T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14) volatile const,Target *)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided

1>c:\cpp_ext\boost\boost_1_47\boost\python\signature.hpp(236) : see declaration of 'boost::python::detail::get_signature'
```

And eventually I get about a hundred copies of error messages very much resembling this one:

```
1>c:\cpp_ext\boost\boost_1_47\boost\python\make_function.hpp(76): error C2784: 'boost::mpl::vector17<RT,ClassT&,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14> boost::python::detail::get_signature(RT (__thiscall ClassT::* )(T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14) volatile const)' : could not deduce template argument for 'RT (__thiscall ClassT::* )(T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14) volatile const' from 'std::string (__cdecl *)(const std::string &,jal::date::JULIAN_DATE,const std::string &,const std::string &,int,const std::string &,const std::string &,const std::string &,const std::string &,const std::string &,const std::string &,int,const std::string &,const std::string &,int,const std::string &,const std::string &,const std::string &,const std::string &,const std::string &,int,const std::string &)'
1>          c:\cpp_ext\boost\boost_1_47\boost\python\signature.hpp(218) : see declaration of 'boost::python::detail::get_signature'
1>c:\cpp_ext\boost\boost_1_47\boost\python\make_function.hpp(76): error C2780: 'boost::mpl::vector17<RT,most_derived<Target,ClassT>::type&,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14> boost::python::detail::get_signature(RT (__thiscall ClassT::* )(T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14) volatile,Target *)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
1>          c:\cpp_ext\boost\boost_1_47\boost\python\signature.hpp(236) : see declaration of 'boost::python::detail::get_signature'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a limit. [You can find those limits here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/python/doc/v2/configuration.html)  It appears to be 15, though I believe you can change it, according to the link.

Comment: Great, thanks for the link!  I wonder why they would impose an arbitrary limit like that if by simply changing the limit the program still works...

I didn't find the part of that link which said it's possible to change that value, can you point me to it please?

Comment: @Derek Without variadic templates(in the new standard) you would have to hand write each version, so you would have to stop somewhere.  As far as ability to change those numbers _using different values of these macros when compiling different libraries (including extension modules and the Boost.Python library itself) is a violation of the ODR. However, we know of no C++ implementations on which this particular violation is detectable or causes any problems._  Why bring it up if you can't actually do it?